# Using localCompare with key passed in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a function to sort various arrays on object, based on a key. Here's my code :

```js
  const sort = (value: keyof TargetTypes) => {
    const sortedTargetsList = targetsList && [...targetsList]
    sortedTargetsList?.sort((a, b) => a[value].localeCompare(b[value]))
  }
```

Then I've an error hovering `localeCompare`saying (Google Trad) :

```
Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | string [] | [] | {platform: string; link: string; userId: string; } [] '.
  Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'false' .ts (2339)
```

Tried various things but can't find a way or even understand what's going wrong. I've tried by hard coding the value like so, and it works : `a['targetName']`

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Can you provide the arrays that you are trying to sort?

Comment: @shobe I can't show you the real one but it's something like this :

`
const targetsList = [
{
targetName: "Target 1",
createdAt: "2022-05-01"
},
{
targetName: "Target 2",
createdAt: "2022-05-02"
}
]
`

Very common..

Comment: You probably have another keys in the object of which type is not string. So try writing compare like this: typeof a[value] === "string" && typeof b[value] === "string" ? a[value].localeCompare(b[value]) : 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by doing this, not sure if it's the better way... Kinda didn't like the eslin disable line but I don't have any clues..

```js
const sort = (value: keyof TargetTypes) => {
  setTargetsList(
    targetsList &&
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      [...targetsList].sort((a: any, b: any) =>
        a[value].localeCompare(b[value]),
      ),
  )
}
```

I prefered this solution over the @shobe one just because it give me suggestions after typing "sort(" to select an available key.